# NodeJS lost connection with Mysql with pool exported

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, pool

I have a Mysql database hosted in a remote server and a Node API hosted in Azure webapps.

The problem is mysql driver lost the connection and can't resume the connection if there is no reboot.

I have been declared a global value at server.js that requires que pool:

```
global.DB = require('./middlewares/database');
```

At database.js:

```
    var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: [SERVER],
    user: [USER],
    password: [PASSWORD],
    database: [DATABASE],
    connectTimeout: 20000,
    adquireTimeout: 20000,
    debug: false
});

exports.query = function (query, params, callback) {

    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            connection.release();
            throw err;
        }

        connection.query(query, params, function (err, rows) {

            connection.release();

            if (!err) {
                callback(null, rows);
            }

        });
        connection.on('error', function (err) {
            connection.release();
            throw err;
        });
    });
```

And then, to make any query from anywhere of the API:

```
 DB.query(queryString, [arguments], function (err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

This work properly at first time but when pass a few minutes:

```
    { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at PoolConnection.Connection._handleConnectTimeout (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:419:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:352:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
    at PoolConnection.connect (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:48:16)
    at Pool.releaseConnection (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:157:10)
    at Pool._removeConnection (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:277:8)
    at Pool._purgeConnection (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:258:8)
    at Ping.onOperationComplete [as _callback] (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:101:12)
    at Ping.Sequence.end (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:86:24)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:399:18
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

I adjust the timeout of the Mysql to 28800 and set the error connections to 1000 without result.

How is the best way to do similar pattern without lost the connection?

Comment: Usually, this is a networking or firewall issue. You mentioned, "*Node API hosted in Azure webapps*", have you tested the code above on your local to check your remote server network whether it works smoothly? Or could you provide more info such as version of Node.js you are using and version of `mysql` module you are using so that we can use to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways on dealing with this issue, to keep your current pattern "neat and clean".

### 1. Recreate the pool

After the error has occurred, you can catch it in 'uncaughtException' or **some other handling mechanism** that will recreate the pool for you.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
...
// MySql Handle
if ('code' in err) {
    if(err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED'){
        db.methodToRecreatePool();
    }
}
...
```

### 2. Restart the service

Other way is to start the node process in the forever cli that will manage node express server for you and once this error is shown, you can restart the node server, and forever cli will start it for you again.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

To start the node server in forever:

```
forever start app.js
```

Hope it helps, update me on how it goes;

Good luck,